# Blend in Adobe Illustrator not working

Tags: adobe-illustrator, blending

I am applying Blend into two different object in Illustrator. One with 100% opacity and  another one with 50%.

I want the blend to be smoothly spread out. but when I select them both and click "blend' (make)
it only creates three shades of circles. I want it to be at least 10 shades and evenly spaced.

I dnt understand why it is only producing three but not 10 or more. I picked blend, smooth color option.

Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Illustrator's Blend defaults to `Smooth Color` even if the objects being blended can't use `Smooth Color` in an expected manner. There are some things the Smooth Color option doesn't see well, *transparency* can be one of them (since it's *not* actually color).

Merely choose `Object > Blend > Blend Options`. Switch to `Specified Steps` and increase the number of steps until you are happy.

[image]

Comment: Awww.. Thank you so much Scott.

Comment: Realize merely using a **radial gradient** in this instance would make the artwork less complex, if that matters.

Comment: can you please check the newly attached image? Why am getting this weird box around my blur? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, yes Radial Gradient should have been the first choice in this case.

Comment: @NeverLookBack please ask a *new question*. Why Illustrator does this is a more complex answer than a comment can provide.

Comment: Okay, I am asking.

Answer (score 3):

Because the colors you're blending are the same, using the Smooth Color option will produce only 1 step between the 2 objects.

From Adobe

> **Smooth Color** Lets Illustrator auto-calculate the number of steps for the blends. If objects are filled or stroked with different
> colors, the steps are calculated to provide the optimum number of
> steps for a smooth color transition. **If the objects contain
> identical colors, or if they contain gradients or patterns, the number
> of steps is based on the longest distance between the bounding box
> edges of the two objects**.

https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/blending-objects.html

If you want additional steps, then Specified Steps would be the best blend option.

[image: Example of using Specified Steps]

If you want the circles to show the overlapping opacity, expand the blend and ungroup the selection of circles.

Comment: Hello,

Thank you.

but I want the transition between Two white shades.. From deep to Transparent/ semi transparent.

Comment: @NeverLookBack You can do that with Specified Steps, I have added a screenshot to my answer.

Comment: Tank you so much <3